# How to display data returned from ajax response as a view in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I'm new to Ajax, and want to return a partial view in laravel in response of an ajax call, so when I click on a link to display the data in a modal it does not work and saying trying to get property of non object. any help?

This is my code:

```
<tr>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;"><?php echo $i;?></td>
    <td>{{ $sale->item_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $sale->brand_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $sale->category_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $sale->fname }} &nbsp; {{ $sale->lname }}</td>
    <td>{{ $sale->sale_date }}</td>
    <td>{{ $sale->quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ $sale->unit_name }}</td>
    <td><span>$</span>{{ $sale->unit_price }} </td>
    <td><span>$</span><?php echo $sale->quantity*$sale->unit_price;?> </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#bill" class="btn btn-xs btn-green mr-5" type="button" tabindex="0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reportModal" onclick="load_modal_data('{{ $sale->sale_id }}','/sales/bill','billContent')">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"> Bill</i></a>
        <a href="/purchase/item" class="btn btn-xs btn-green mr-5"><i class="fa fa-search"> View</i></a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-lightred"><i class="fa fa-remove"> Del</i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**The JS and Ajax**

```
function load_modal_data(identity, route,target_tag)
{
    $.ajax({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') },
        url: route,
        type:'post',
        data:{ id: identity},
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result)
            $('#'+target_tag).html(result);
        }
    })
}
```

**The Controller:**

```
public function bill()
{
    $id = Input::get('identity');
    $sales = DB::table('sales')
        ->join('brands','brands.bid','=','sales.brand_id')
        ->join('units','units.unit_id','=','sales.unit_id')
        ->join('categories','categories.cat_id', '=','sales.category_id')
        ->join('customers','customers.cid','=','sales.c_id')
        ->select('sales.*','brands.brand_name','categories.category_name','customers.fname','customers.lname','units.unit_name')
        ->where('sales.sale_id',$id)->first();
    $returnHTML = view('partials.item-bill')->with('sales',$sales)->render();
    return response()->json(array('success'=>true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
}
```

This is my **item-bill.blade.php**

```
<!-- tile body -->
<div class="tile-body p-0">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table mb-0" id="usersList">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:20px;">No</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Sale Date</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $sales->item_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $sales->brand_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $sales->category_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $sales->fname }} &nbsp; {{ $sales->lname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $sales->sale_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $sales->quantity }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $sales->unit_name }}</td>
                    <td><span>$</span>{{ $sales->unit_price }} </td>
                    <td><span>$</span><?php echo $sales->quantity*$sales->unit_price;?> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Note: I'm using Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you need to change is here:

```
$('#'+target_tag).html(result.html);
```

You get an json as a response with `result.html`;

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried it but still the same error

Comment: OK - what error you gets? And could you console.log(result) and check whats inside?

Comment: The error in the console : jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/sales/bill 500 (Internal Server Error)   and in Laravel Debugbar : Saying -> Trying to get property of non-object   from my partial  page

Comment: can you `dd($sales)` after you get it from DB. There're many inner joins that  can filter out your result and you can get there `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the issue and want to share here.
I did the following steps:

1. changing the route method from **GET** to **POST**

   ```
   Route::post('sales/bill/{id}','SalesController@bill');
   ```
2. changing the parameters of js **function load_modal_data()**

   ```
   <a href="#bill" ...  onclick="load_modal_data('/sales/bill/{{ $sale->sale_id }}','billContent')">
   ```
3. changing the above function in js file as well:

   ```
   function load_modal_data(route,target_tag)
   {
   var identity = route.substring(route.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
   // $('#'+target_tag).addClass('animation-loading')
   $.ajax({
       headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') },
       url: route,
       type:'post',
       data:{ id: identity},
       success:function(result){
           $('#'+target_tag).html(result.html);
       },
       error: function (result) {
           alert('Ooops something went wrong!');
       }
   });
   ```

   }
4. And the controller as well,

   ```
   public function bill($id)
    {
       .
       .
       .
    }
   ```

Now it's working.